# How can i access cfs url from a remote non dse (datastax) node

Tags: cassandra, datastax

im am trying to do... from my prog.

val file = sc.textFile("cfs://ip/.....")

but i get java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: cfs exception...

How should i modify the core-site.xml and where? It should be on dse nodes or should i add it as a resource in my jar.
I use maven to build my jar and execute the jobs remotely...from a non dse node which does not have cassandra or spark or something similar... Other type of flows without cfs files work ok... so the jar is ok so far...

Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

There is some info in the middle of this page about Spark using Hadoop for some operations, such as CFS access:  http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkCassProps.html

I heard about a problem using Hive from a non-DSE node that was solved by adding a property file to core-site.xml. This is really a long-shot since it's Spark, but if you're willing to experiment, try adding the IP address of the remote machine to the core-site.xml file.

```
<property>
 <name>cassandra.host</name>
 <value>192.168.2.100</value>
<property>
```

Find the core-site.xml in /etc/dse/hadoop/conf/ or install_location/resources/hadoop/conf/, depending on the type of installation.

I assume you started the DSE cluster in hadoop and spark mode: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkStart.html

Comment: I have tried this (adding it to core-site.xml) but with no result: <property>
 <name>fs.cfs.impl</name>
 <value>com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.CassandraFileSystem</value>
</property> because i didnt see it in the cluster configuration taken from here:http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-file-system-design so i thought it was an issue of missing impl although the cfs keyspaces were set in cassandra cluster. Yes both spark and hadoop are enabled. I am trying to execute remote jobs because it sees more proper and probaly faster for production. I will try that thnx.

Answer (score -1):

Been quite some time.

The integration is done as usual with any integration of a hadoop client to a compatible hadoop fs.
Copy core-site.xml (append the dse-core-default.xml there)  along with dse.yaml, cassandra.yaml and then it requires a proper dependency set-up in the class path eg. dse.jar, cassandra-all, etc.

Note: this is not officially supported so better use other way.

Comment: -1 is for text quality or technical info? I think a summary result is better than several pages of code or setup... anyway i think the post is really useful for anyone trying the same... it is a hint post...